# Bigquery numeric datetime to string datetime

Tags: sql, date, datetime, time, google-bigquery

I have written a query in bigquery like below:

```
 SELECT date_trunc(dd.created, week) AS week,
  COUNT(DISTINCT dd.user) AS total,
  COUNT(dd.upload) AS info
FROM
  local.detail dd
  LEFT JOIN local.list du ON dd.id = du.id
WHERE
  regexp_extract(du.email, r '@(.+)') != 'gmail.com'
GROUP BY
  date_trunc(dd.created, week);
```

**Output:**

| week | total | info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-02 00:00:00 | 625 | 382 |
| 2020-03-22 00:00:00 | 1059 | 329 |

i want the week_signup column data format like this(just month and day):

| week | total | info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feb 02 | 625 | 382 |
| Mar 03 | 1059 | 329 |

How can i write this in bigquery to get this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [format_date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) for the same.

E.g. `FORMAT_DATE("%a %d", date_trunc(dd.created_date, week))`

Comment: with FORMAT_DATE() i get this error: SELECT list expression references dd.created_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:34]

Comment: Did you replace the function in GROUP BY clause as well?

Comment: Got it now. I used "%b %d" for month and date. Thank you for the help